# jquery file upload blueimp dimensions

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp, dimensions

Using the Jquery File Upload script found here, https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ is it possible to check the image dimensions before it gets uploaded on the server?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible by enabling the image resizing.

You can read the wiki here:

[jQuery-File-Upload Client-side-Image-Resizing](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing)

Comment: This uploads the image first and then checking.